# The exe file generated by PyInstaller does not work

Tags: python, pyinstaller

PyInstaller previously worked very well.
However, after installing Jupyter, the new generated exe files by PyInstaller did not work,for instance, warning no module named Tkinter.
If uninstall Jupyter and generate the exe file by PyInstaller again, the new exe file  works well.

Is there any conflict between the two? 
How to solve this problem? I want to keep Jupyter installed.

Comment: Try installing Tkinter http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html

Comment: Tkinter has been included in Python. After uninstalling Jupyter,  the new exe file generated from the same py file works well, no warning 'no module named Tkinter'.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changing the modules' order.

Old order:
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import pylab
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource, Normalize,LinearSegmentedColormap

New order:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import pylab
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource, Normalize,LinearSegmentedColormap
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog